# Celery tasks end up in an inconsistent state after a polite worker restart

Tags: celery, django-celery

I have a celery service on my server. I start it with `celery multi start...` and stop with `celery multi stopwait...`. This works fine, when stopwait is called, it waits for all workers to finish their tasks, then exits.

I call both `start` and `stopwait` with the `-E` flag, and I use `django_celery_monitor` to monitor tasks:

```
celery events -A myapp --camera django_celery_monitor.camera.Camera --frequency=2.0
```

This works too, I get the event status recorded into the database, and tasks are updated correctly.

The problem occurs however when I use `stopwait` to stop a worker. If a task is running, that task remains in the `STARTED` state forever, even though it has completed, I'm guessing because the event is emitted but since the worker shuts down immediately afterwards it gets lost. The updated status is never received, and I can't simply overwrite them myself since the Camera class writes the incorrect status back over the top when it runs.

I have even experimented with Real-time processing using callbacks instead of the supplied Camera class. The successful task event is still not received from the final task before the worker is terminated.

How can I get around this problem? My backend is RabbitMQ. Celery version is 4.1.0.